# How to easily find limits in transformation problems

Tags: probability

If X and Y has joint pdf, f(x,y) =1 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1, and we want to find the pdf of Z = X +Y what is an easy way to do this? The hard part about this problem is determining the limits. When I employ the Jacobian method, I create another variable Q = Y and find the pdf of Z and Q. But when I find the marginal of Z, the bounds for Q is between 0 and z where 0 < z < 1 since  Q = Y. But what happens if 1 < z < 2? I am stuck in finding the pdf.

Comment: Draw a square with opposite vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Draw a line $x+y=z$ where $1 < z < 2$. This line will cross the square, dividing it into a triangle and a pentagon.  Then, $P\{X+Y > z\} = 1 - F_{X+Y}(z)$ is the area of the triangle (in this simple case) which you should be able to express as a function of $z$, and you can find that for $1 < z < 2$, $$f_{X+Y}(z) = -\frac{d}{dz}P\{X+Y > z\} = 2-z.$$ If you draw the line $x+y=z$ for $0 < z < 1$, you can similarly get $P\{X+Y<z\}$ as the area of a triangle, and $f_{X+Y}(z) = z$ for $0 < z < 1$. No muss, no fuss, no $Q=Y$, no Jacobians.

Comment: Why couldn't you do this using the Jacobian method? Will the Jacobian method not work here?

Comment: You tried and failed in using the Jacobian method. I suggested to you a simpler method, **which I had also suggested to you in response to a [question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74085/15941) about five months ago in an answer that you accepted**.  Yes, the Jacobian method will work here.  **You** can use the Jacobian method if you like; **I** will refuse to use the Jacobian method in solving this problem, and I will not help you with doing it that way either.  Wait for someone else to post the complete answer via the Jacobian method.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is $0\leqslant Q\leqslant Z$ if $0\leqslant Z\leqslant1$ and $Z-1\leqslant Q\leqslant 1$ if $1\leqslant Z\leqslant2$.